# TextBoxFor for decimal ignoring comma as my decimal seperator despite globalization set to da-DK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple `TextBoxFor`, which I am using on a decimal. My decimal is simply defined as the following in my viewmodel:

```
    [DisplayName("Beløb")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

I use this in my form, using:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Amount, new { @class = "col-lg-3 control-label text-lg-right pt-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Amount)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, in my web.config, I have set globalization under `system.web`:

```
<globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK" />
```

**My problem is the following:**

The following are how we would write a number in Denmark:

500,50 <-- fivehundred and fifty cents

If I POST this to the server, the comma is ignored, and my controller receives 50050.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought the web.config would be enough.

Comment: This may or may not help, but I could not reproduce the problem you have - the posted value included the comma. You could try: protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");} in global.asax instead of the web.config setting to see if that gives you a clue (a long shot, not based on any evidence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an error no one on StackOverflow would've been able to fix, because I did not provide the full picture. I will leave the answer here just in case someone else Googles this and it's just one more place to look in desperate times.

The error was in my Global.asax. I had set up two model binders for decimals:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

And my code was:

```
 public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Equals("N.aN") ||
                valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Equals("NaN") ||
                valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Equals("Infini.ty") ||
                valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Equals("Infinity") ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue))
            {
                return 0m;
            }

            try
            {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0m;
            }
        }
    }
```

After fixing this, it just worked. Obviously. I'm an idiot ;)